# Android- Flip horizontal animation between two images

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, viewflipper

I am trying to create an animation of two images. I want the image, when clicked, it flips horizontally 180 degrees to the new image (front to back) just like a card.  I  want to perform this with multiple images on the layout. How can i write this code once and call it when i want it performed?

Answer (score 2):

```
In Resource->Create anim folder->xml file with any name



     <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <scale
            android:fromXScale=".3"
            android:toXScale="1.0"
            android:fromYScale="0.3"
            android:toYScale="1.0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:duration="800" />

        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:toDegrees="180"

            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:duration="800" />

</set>
```

Now you can use this animation anywhere and no of times as well